# Coding style: Is this a good way to write a function

Tags: r

Is the following code example, calling a function in the parameters line of another function, acceptable? Or will I run in problems somehow?

```r
newfunction <- function(df = merge_two_df(), size = define_size()){
    ... do something
}
```

Comment: At least *base* is also calling a function in the parameters line. E.g. `ls`

Comment: True. Thank you!

Comment: I think it's fine as long as you make sure that the parameter functions will be available always when yours is called.

Comment: should be ok but you may end up with code that can be hard to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically a question of what you gain and lose compared to the alternatives.

So first let's look at the alternatives:

Option1

```r
newfunction <- function(){
    df = merge_two_df(), size = define_size()
    ... do something
}
```

Option2

```r
newfunction <- function(df,size){
    ... do something
}

newfunction(merge_two_df(),define_size())
```

Comparing your status-quo to option 1 shows that your current way is more flexible. You have defined default values for each parameter but retain the option to use other parameters. So there is nothing to gain hard-coding the parameter definition into the body of the function.

Now comparing to option 2, your current way is actually more standardized because you have defined defaults. You can simply and cleanly call your function without any parameters while having the same flexibility of switching up parameters if you want. However on the flip side you are a bit less explicit in calling these parameters which might be bad in terms of documentation and clarity when rereading the code.

If this function is part of a module that might be used/exported across several projects some even done by someone other then yourself, then I'd argue for option 2 to be simpler and clearer.

Otherwise what you do right now works best.